# Unable to read xsd file in resources folder in jboss server app

Tags: java, jboss

1) I am trying to read a xsd file placed in resources folder in java.

2) We are using JBoss Server for our Application.

3) Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(classLoader.getResource("Abc.xsd").getFile()));

4) I am getting the following exception - C:\dev\jboss-eap-7.0\bin\content\batch.war\WEB-INF\lib\common-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar\Abc.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified).

5) It is somehow appending C:\dev\jboss-eap-7.0\bin\ before the file path.

Could anyone please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a file system path, but use `classLoader.getResourceAsStream("abcd.xsd")`. Of course your `abcd.xsd` file must be in classpath for the WAR file classLoader and addressed from the root. (for that example file is in the root level for WAR file classes or one of jar file visible by WAR file classLoader).

Points are: WAR file ClassLoader is isolated and classes and resources loaded by WAR file's classLoader are not directly from the file system path where WAR file is.

Comment: I get the following exception when I use getResourceAsStream("abcd.xsd") - 

Exception : C:\dev\jboss-eap-7.0\bin\java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream@77ce4e82 (The system cannot find the file specified)
"

Comment: It is about classpath I told. so check: 1. what classLoader do you use? 2. where is a class from where you call it? 3. is it in WAR file? if so you you have to use its classLoader and first place for your resource is inside WAR `WEB-INF/classes` or one of the JAR files in the WAR. If you need to have your resource outside of WAR it could be one of the JBoss Module: system, global or custom defined in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file as dependency or resource for your WAR file. As resource you can define file system path to the resource directory as `resource-root` element.

Comment: Thanks...It worked with getResourceAsStream.
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(xsdFile));